# How do I improve the following piece of code in constructor method?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

```
auto MyName = "Luffy";
for (auto &student: students)
{
    if (student.name == MyName)
    {
        m_student_info = &student;
    }
}
```

students is a struct with names and rollnumbers declared somewhere with values. How do I improve this piece of code inside a constructor? return cannot be used inside the constructor. even when student.name finds a match, it still continues to run in loop, how to avoid that?

Comment: *"return cannot be used inside the constructor"* - Is that so? Have you tried to `return;`?

Comment: How about a `break;` in the `if`? If you want to continue in the function after the loop.

Comment: You can't return a value but you can certainly return from a constructor.

Comment: yes, I tried. constructor doesn't expect a return value. I just need to initialize/assign value to m_student_info.

Comment: @Luffy555 - No, not return *a value*. Just return, like from a void function

Comment: you could also call a function that returns something in the constructor. Anyhow this piece of code doesn't look like it belongs inside a constructor directly.

Comment: and also is it possible to optimize the for loop here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialise the member with a function

```
Student* find_student(std::string name, Students & students)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(students.begin(), students.end(), [&name](auto & student){ return student.name == name; });
    return (it != students.end()) ? &*it : nullptr;
}

Thing::Thing() : m_student_info(find_student("Luffy", students)) {}
```

Comment: m_student_info = std::find_if(std::begin(students), std::end(students), [&name](auto &student) { return student.name == name; }); I have code like this which works but how do I check if m_student_info is nullptr or not before initializing completes in constructor?

Comment: I am not using this find_if with a function but directly inside the constructor.

Comment: What do you plan on doing if it fails to find in the constructor? If you don't want an object lacking a `Student` then you need to search before, and construct one if you find one. At which point the constructor can take the `Student *` that is known to be not null

Answer (score 1):

**break;** directive is used to immediatelly stop the execution of the loop. It also works with other loops, like *while*.

The main improvement for your constructor, is to add **break** at the end of your *if*, if you wish to stop looping after the match has been found.

Note that break will not exit the function - just the loop.